# Probability Proof.

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing, conditional-probability

Write a proof to show that $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \mid X_3) + \mathbb{P}(X_2 \mid X_3) -  \mathbb{P}(C_1 \cap X_2 \mid X_3) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \cup X_2\mid X_3)$ labeling theorems used for each step.

My attempt:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
\mathbb{P}(X_1 \cup X_2\mid X_3)&=& \frac{\mathbb{P}((X_1 \cup X_2)\cap X_3)}{\mathbb{P}(X_3)} \\
&=&\mathbb{P}((X_1 \mid X_3) \cap (X_2 \mid X_3))\\
&=& \mathbb{P}(X_1 \mid X_3)+\mathbb{P}(X_2 \mid X_3)-\mathbb{P}(X_1 \cap X_2 \mid X_3)
\end{array}$$

Comment: Omitting parentheses is dangerous here... To fill the ????, write down $(X_1\cup X_2)\cap X_3$ as the union of two well chosen sets.

Comment: You may want to look at some of the laws for manipulating expressions involving sets:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that $\Pr(W|X_3)=\dfrac{\Pr(W\cap X_3)}{\Pr(X_3)}$.

Then let $Y_1=X_1\cap X_3$, and $Y_2=X_2\cap X_3$.

Note that $(X_1\cap X_2)\cap X_3=Y_1\cap Y_2$ and $(X_1\cup X_2)\cap X_3=Y_1\cup Y_2$.

Then the thing you are wanting to prove basically comes down to
$$\Pr(Y_1)+\Pr(Y_2)-\Pr(Y_1\cap Y_2)=\Pr(Y_1\cup Y_2),$$
which is a familiar fact. Just divide by $\Pr(X_3)$, and use the facts about $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ listed above.

Comment: Am I missing any details on my new attempt?

Comment: Looks fine. Please put proper parentheses in the first line!

Comment: I removed the answer from the question so people can think about it without the answer already there.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Bayes' rule everywhere on the left-hand side:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_1 \mid X_3) + \mathbb{P}(X_2 \mid X_3) -  \mathbb{P}(X_1 \cap X_2 \mid X_3)&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1 \cap X_3)+\mathbb{P}(X_2 \cap X_3)-  \mathbb{P}(X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3)}{\mathbb{P}(X_3)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1\cup X_2\cap X_3)}{\mathbb{P}(X_3)}\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_1\cup X_2\mid X_3)
\end{align}